# Hom(A, B) Cathegory theory

Tags: category-theory

What this construction Hom(A, B) means? I did not found anything that explains clearly.
For example $Hom(N, N_{\bot})$

N is the set of natural numbers,

$N_{\bot} = N \cup \bot$ It is a notation for patial functions. f(x) = $\bot$ if the computation of the function never ends.

Context:
For the functional F defined below the following functions from $Hom(N, N_{\bot})$ are fixed points

F = $\lambda g.\lambda n .$if n = 0 then 0 else if n=1 then g(1) else g(n-2)+2

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain the context in which your question arises please?

Comment: Added the context, sorry

Comment: More context would still be helpful.  For instance, what are $N$ and $N_{\perp}$?

Comment: Added more context $N_{}

Comment: $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ is the set of morphisms (in the category of interest) from object $A$ to object $B$. Often this set carries additional structure, for example in the category of vector spaces over a field $k$, $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ is itself a vector space (per pointwise addition/multiplication). It is not clear which category you are working in, otherwise more could be said for the specific case